# Survey, does this make sense?

Tags: survey, likert

I'm trying to learn a bit of statistics, and I thought I'd ask you guys about conducting surveys.

Let's say I conduct a survey like the following https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1YrqcWQNl1CmbINaVZuL18ZseqBSWemdHjy_P4ES637A/viewform

I am surveying a lot of cyclists and I want to know how they are motivated. 
Different questions describes different types of motivation (seven categories of motivation with 4 questions in each category).

Does it make sense to do any statistics on this? For example I would think testing whether one type of motivation is significantly more prevalent than another. 
I guess I am comparing the different groups (of motivation). I'm not sure if this is a Likert scale.

If you guys have any suggestions on which types of tests I should do, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things you can do with survey data, but you have the cart before the horse. You shouldn't be asking what statistics you can do with the data, you should be asking what statistics can answer the questions you have, and then listing some questions. (Actually, ideally, you should have done this before designing the survey, but you've got what you've got).